# Integration of $e^{ax}\cos^n bx$ and $e^{ax}\sin^n bx$

Tags: complex-integration, reduction-formula

> **Q**: Integration of $e^{ax}\cos^n bx$ and $e^{ax}\sin^n bx$

I know how to integration $e^{ax}\cos bx$ using $\cos bx=\frac{e^{ibx}+e^{-ibx}}{2}$.Using the same trick here I got $$\int e^{ax}\cos^n bx ~dx=\int e^{ax}\left(\frac{e^{ibx}+e^{-ibx}}{2}\right)^n~ dx$$But it doesn't look easy to solve.I google it and find the result only which is:

> $$\int e^{ax}\cos^n bx ~dx=\frac{bn\sin (bx)+a\cos (bx)}{a^2+b^2n^2}e^{ax}\cos^{n-1}bx+\frac{b^2(n-1)n\int e^{ax}\cos^{n-2}bxdx}{a^2+b^2n^2}.$$

Can Anyone help me to figure out this. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That "result" is a reduction formula, proved by integrating by parts.

Comment: You can expand your formula by the binomial theorem and integrate termwise.

Comment: If i use binomial theorem then it will consume a lot of time.Is there any other way to figure out this @Lord Shark the Unknown Sir

Comment: As alreasy said, integrate by parts to get the reduction formula.

Comment: You may look at the method I used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3003466/394456).

Comment: Going by parts is the easiest way

Comment: Since everyone prefer me do the integration by parts, i tried it.but i can't get any recursion part.For seek of complete answer can anyone do it by parts. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Differentiation is easier than integration)

Let $f_{m,a, b}(x)=f_m=e^{ax}\cos^m bx$. Take the derivative of $f_{m}$,
\begin{align*}
f'_{m}&=af_{m}-bmf_{m-1}\sin bx.\tag{1}
\end{align*}
So, if we take $g_{m}=af_{m}\color{magenta}+bmf_{m-1}\sin bx$, the derivative of $g_{m}$ will cancel $\color{blue}{\sin bx}$ out, i.e.
\begin{align*}
g'_{m}&=af'_{m}\hspace{8.2em}+bm\big(f'_{m-1}\sin bx\hspace{10.8em}+b\underbrace{f_{m-1}\cos bx}_{=f_{m}}\big)\\
g'_{m}&=a^2f_{m}-\color{blue}{abmf_{m-1}\sin bx}+\color{blue}{bm}\big(\color{blue}{af_{m-1}\sin bx}-b(m-1) f_{m-2}\color{orange}{\sin^2 bx}+bf_m\big)\\
g'_{m}&=(a^2+b^2m)f_m-b^2m(m-1)f_{m-2}\color{orange}{(1-\cos^2 bx)}\\
g'_{m}&=(a^2+b^2m^2)f_m-b^2m(m-1)f_{m-2}.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Now, we assume 
$$I_{m}=\int f_m~\mathrm dx=\int e^{ax}\cos^m bx~\mathrm dx,$$
integrate $(2)$, we get the desired result

> $$g_m=(a^2+b^2m^2)I_{m}-b^2m(m-1)I_{m-2}.$$

Comment: Thanks @Tianlalu Really appreciated.Can i use Differentiation to get Integration in this way always?

Comment: Yes, we can always do so once we find the appropriate $f_m$. For example, for $\int \cos^n x~dx$, we may choose $f_n=\cos^{n-1}x \sin x$ and differentiate it to cancel $\sin x$ out.